# In Reactjs, what is the industry standard why to get a visitor's IP, Country, etc.?

Tags: java, reactjs, web, geolocation, ip

https://geolocation-db.com/json/

When I visit the website above, it shows:

```
{"country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","city":"Some_City","postal":"xxxxx","latitude":xx.9229,"longitude":-xx.6483,"IPv4":"xx.xx.xx.xx","state":"Some_State"}
```

This is basically all of the info that I want.

For APPs that are coded in React, what is the industry standard way to get this info?

How do websites like LinkedIn and Twitter do it?

Comment: You can contract one services about apis for example https://www.appgate.com/has the services about that, also you can create the backend service that permits to get this informations with spring boot is easy

Comment: There is no industry standard in get IP geolocation. There are many vendors such as Maxmind, IP2Location and etc.